# Converting VB6 application Vb.Net using Interop

Tags: interop

I have a fairly large application, written  in VB6.  I want to convert it to Vb.Net using Interop, but donot know how to do it.
The application is so big that I really can't re-write it in VB.Net.
Thanks and best regards,
Furqan

Comment: You should consider using VB.NET 2008 code migration wizard that can convert your VB6 project into VB.NET, I don't know what you mean by "using interop", but for migration, only 2008 can be used as 2010 no longer has this feature.

Comment: Thanks !!! Could you advise where I can find Code Migration Wizard?

Comment: Sorry for appearing lately. Code migration wizard will automatically open when you'll try to open VB6 project file in Visual Studio 2008. But keep in mind that conversion will not fully convert the project out-of-the-box, you'll manually need to add some references in case you've done so in VB6 project initially.